# EagleCAD symbol shows 4 leads for 3 lead voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, eaglecad

I'm curious as to why the following image of a [MCP1827S-3302E/EB](http://za.rs-online.com/web/p/low-dropout-voltage-regulators/7239836/?searchTerm=723-9836&relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E525353746F636B4E756D6265724D504E266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C26706D3D5E5C647B337D5B5C732D2F255C2E2C5D5C647B332C347D2426706F3D313426736E3D592673743D52535F53544F434B5F4E554D424552267573743D3732332D393833362677633D4E4F4E4526) voltage regulator, which has three legs shows up with 4 legs in EagleCAD.

[image: Voltage Regulator Symbol]

I noticed that there are two ground pins, GND and GND_2 in the schematic, why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the ground pins on the schematic symbol represents the exposed pad on the device package, which should be connected to ground on the PCB.

The exposed pad is visible at the rear side in  the image below:

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is no longer necessary in Eagle 6, they made it possible to assign one schematic pin to multiple pads on the physical package. This was not previously the case.